# Shiny-server with a proxy Not Working after wordpress multisite added as subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, shiny-server, subdirectory, multisite

I have been using the wordpress, shiny-server and RStudio-server on Nginx + Ubuntu 14.04.

Wordpress was installed on a root.
Shiny-server was installed per default procedures.

I added the following codes to /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_site_addresscom.conf to run shiny-server on my_site_address.com/shiny/.

```
 location /shiny/ {
  proxy_pass http://my_site_address.com:3838/;
 }
```

At this point, wordpress and shiny-server worked fine.

After that, I decided to add the new wordpress in subdirectory, following the procedures on [this site](http://www.itworld.com/article/2871918/how-to-configure-nginx-for-wordpress-multisite-with-subdirectories.html). 
Installed Nginx helper plugin, and added the following codes to /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_site_addresscom.conf.

```
map $http_host $blogid {
    default 0;
    include /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/nginx-helper/map.conf;
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/files/(.*)$ {
  try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/$uri /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 ;
  access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
}

location ^~ /blogs.dir {
        internal;
        alias /var/www/html/wp-content/blogs.dir ;
        access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
}


if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```

After that, I cannot access to shiny-server with 
my_site_address.com/shiny/ while I can access with my_site_address.com:3838/.

Could you please advise me what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Self-solved.

It seems that

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { ...
```

section conflicts with

```
location /shiny/ { ...
```

section.

The problem has been solved with modifying '/shiny/' section as follows:

```
location ^~ /shiny/ { proxy_pass my_site_address.com:3838; }
```

Thanks and hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. One note: I needed a forward slash after 3838 for this to work. My location block looked like this: `location ^~ /shiny/ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;}`